# Is it ok to use vinyl sheet as a temp cover for a boiler flue hole?

Tags: safety, boiler

[image]I have an unsealed boiler flue hole like the picture:

I was going to acquire and use some vinyl sheet however I have just realized I have some cushion vinyl lying around.

As a temporary fix, will it be ok to use that?  Or can the heat from the boiler cause the vinyl to heat up and be dangerous?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no picture.... and not my DV.

Comment: @JACK sorry.  have uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vinyl would be OK to seal this but don't fit your vinyl so tight that it comes in contact with the flue. Leave a gap between the flue and vinyl, the pipe collar will over the gap.

Comment: Good idea on using the collar - completely escaped me.  Top marks.  Thanks!!